# Removing a list item after appending it

Tags: jquery

I have the following code,

```
     $('.button').click(function(){
    var inputItem = $('.listItem').val();
    $('.thelist').append('<li class="item">'+inputItem+'</li><span        class="delete">delete</span>');    
});

 //TRYING TO REMOVE THE ITEM
 $(document).on('click','.delete',function(){
    $(this).remove(function(){
        $('.item').remove();
    });
 });
```

I'm still pretty new to jQuery, can anyone point me in the right direction please. Thanks

Comment: You can't have `<span>`s as children of `<ul>` elements.

Comment: Try `$(this).remove(function(){
        $(this).closest('li.item').remove();
    });`

Comment: Ah yes you're right, span is in the wrong place. The question is, whenever someone clicks on the span with the class of delete, it deletes the span along with the list item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do something like this instead:

```
var $delete = $('<span>', {
    'class': 'delete',
    'text': 'delete'
});

$('.button').click(function () {
    $('<li>', {
        'class': 'item',
        'html': $('.listItem').val()
    }).append($delete.clone()).appendTo('.thelist');
});

$('.thelist').on('click', '.delete', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

You can disregard the other changes that I made, but `$(this).parent().remove();` is what removes the `<li>` element that corresponds to the `<span>`.

`$(this).closest('li.item').remove();` will work even if the `<span>` isn't a child of `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please see this code snippet if it satisfies your query:

```
var index=0;   //mock index variable
$('button').click(function (e){
   $('#theList').append('<span><li class="delete">hello world ' + index+ '</li></span>' ); 
    e.stopPropagation();   //stop bubbling of event

    index= index+1;
});


$(document).click(function (){ //click anywhere but the button and all <li> items disappear.
   $('.delete').remove();
});
```

You can check this [jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/KevinIsNowOnline/waGT2/) for more information.